# How to pass parameters in https GET request for (Shopware) Rest API

Tags: api, url, https, request, shopware

As far as I understood, GET-Requests encode the parameters throught the url. I want to specify data that I get from the shopware REST-API (https://myshopurl/api/orders).

If I append ?limit=1, that works. But now I want to sort the results first.
The Shopware [Rest API documentation](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/) says:

```
$params = [
    'sort' => [
        ['property' => 'name']
    ]
];

$client->get('articles', $params);
```

or

```
$params = [
    'sort' => [
        ['property' => 'orderTime'],
        ['property' => 'invoiceAmount', 'direction' => 'DESC']
    ]
];

$client->get('orders', $params);
```

but I am not sure how to build the URL from this information, because there are parameters within an array. Where do I have to write down the "sort" and do I have to use some brackets?

I hope somebody can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to put the filter in the url. Here is an example:

```
http://mydomain/api/orders?filter[0][property]=customer.email&filter[0][value]=my@domain.de
```

This is the exact example from here: https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/#filter,-sort,-limit,-offset

Comment: Thanks! That works for filter and is already usefull for me, but I didn't manage to sort in descending order yet, probably I'm still missing something. I tried

    ?sort[0][property]=orderTime&sort[0]direction=DESC

and

    ?sort[0][property]=orderTime,direction=DESC

both didn't work...

Comment: http://webserver/latest/api/orders?sort[0][property]=orderTime&sort[1][property]=invoiceAmount&sort[1][direction]=DESC

You can download the APIClient from the documentation and use the examples. I just added a die in the GET-Method and dumpled the url :)

Comment: The sorting works, I simply forgot the brackets... I didn't quite understand your last comment :/ where can I download the client? The only thing I require in addition is to filter orders in a range (e.G to get todays and yesterdays orders). Thanks so much for helping again, sorry for annoying so much -.-

Comment: got it... I added [expression]=>=

Comment: You can find the api client here: https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/#creating-the-api-client